# Announcing a Pro Tempore Moderator election

Tags: discusión, elecciones

**Summary**: Spanish Language Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **September 9** to bring in two more moderators.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on September 9, users can [nominate themselves](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On September 16, if there are three or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on September 24.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

#### Is the timeline fixed?

[Historically](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42104018#42104018), July and August (along with Easter and Christmas) have been low-traffic months for this site. We are already experiencing this:

[image: 2019 stats]

This is because these are the months for summer break in Spain and several Latin America countries (including most of those in the Northern Hemisphere as well as Peru and some regions of Colombia); and, for countries in the Southern Hemisphere like Argentina, Chile... it is rather too close to the end of school's winter break.
Given that a good part of our community is comprised of students, it is understandable that participation on the site goes hand in hand with school periods. For this very same reason, October and November (and maybe the second half of September) are the months with the highest traffic and participation.

**I believe it's desirable for any election to have a high voter turnout. Because of this, I think it'd be positive to move the election to the second half of September.**

A point could be made about the new mods needing some time to learn the ropes, and a high-traffic period not being the best moment to do so. However, I don't think that'd be an issue: we've been doing OK with just two active mods for some years now; we can survive a couple months more while they adapt, if that means they will be backed up by a greater share of our community.

Comment: The election can be moved, no worries — the only bit we need to make sure of first, though, is whether the current team (minus the mods stepping down) needs to have the "full team" ready ASAP, or if it can wait for ~1 month before that happens.

Comment: It sounds logic. We current moderators do not have problem with waiting a bit to have the full team on board, so waiting until September sounds good. Hopefully will come with many good candidates and debates around the election. cc @JNat

Comment: Moved it to September 9th, after discussing it with the mods :)

Answer (score 3):

¿Hay algún requisito **imprescindible** para presentarse a las elecciones? Por ejemplo: tener determinada reputación y/o antigüedad, dominio de idiomas, etc.

Comment: Además de tener una reputación de 300 (como dice la [página de las elecciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/1)) no se puede haber estado suspendido en el último año. En las elecciones de sitios graduados suele pedirse un mínimo de medallas, pero en nuestras elecciones Pro Tem esto no ocurre. Mira [There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360/209901), si bien lo indicado allí es sobre las elecciones de sitios graduados.

Comment: @fedorqui - Esto me crea una duda, porque creí que nuestro sitio ya se graduó.

Comment: @aparente001 a mí también me crea duda :D Estamos pseudograduados en el sentido de ya no ser Beta, pero no tenemos las funcionalidades de un sitio plenamente graduado (diseño propio, reputación necesaria para privilegios más elevada, etc)

Comment: @fedorqui: Gracias por la información. Por lo que veo en tu primer enlace (https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/1) no se pide **ningún requisito especial**, mientras que en el segundo (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work) se establecen varios: **reputación > 300, no suspensión en último año, y determinadas medallas** (Civic Duty, Strunk & White, Deputy y Convention) ...

Comment: @fedorqui: Claro que por otro lado hay diferencias en el proceso entre lo indicado en (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work) y lo recogido aquí (https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/1), por ejemplo los dos párrafos finales de"Pase 1 : Nomination" ....

Comment: Rotten: al ser este un proceso nuevo, es mejor fijarse en ejemplos que en la documentación de Meta.SE. Consulté con otros moderadores cuyo sitio tuvo elecciones Pro Tem y allí no hubo requisitos de medallas, solo 300 rep + no suspensión en un año.

Comment: @walen Cuando hubo elecciones en Freelance SE, creo que había 2 vacantes, inicialmente no se nominó nadie, y luego una sola persona que, lógicamente, fue nombrada ...  https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/election-phase-started-with-no-candidates   , https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295/nominate-yourself-for-freelancing-se-moderatorship y https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301/2019-community-moderator-election-results

Answer (score 2):

¿Hay algún requisito **imprescindible** para **votar** a los que se presenten a las elecciones?  Por ejemplo: tener determinada reputación y/o antigüedad, medallas, etc.
Por lo que veo en [There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work) parece que se requiere una **reputación mínima de 150**, pero no tengo claro si eso se aplica en nuestro caso (ya que alguna regla es diferente.) Por ejemplo, los 2 párrafos finales de "Phase 1 : Nomination" indican:

> After 7 days, the top 30 nominees ordered by reputation advance to the primary phase. If there are ten or fewer nominees (but at least one more than the number of moderator slots being filled by the election), then we skip directly to the election phase.
>
> If the number of nominees is less than or equal to the number of moderator slots the election will add, this phase will be extended by another seven days. If this is still the case once the extended period is over, the election will either be cancelled entirely (on graduated sites) or the nominee(s) will be made pro-tem moderators (on beta sites).

Mientras que en estas elecciones se indica (para 2 vacantes):

> On September 16, if there are three or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidates.

Comment: As you noted, 150 reputation is the only requirement to vote in candidates for the election, indeed.

Comment: @JNat Thank you for the clarification