# 2022 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discusión, elecciones, moderadores

The 2022 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: En estas parece que puedes elegir candidato pero no hacerles preguntas ni nada? Hay algún hilo en meta con preguntas y respuestas de estos candidatos? Sé que este comentario/sugerencia llega un poco tarde, pero se me acaba de ocurrir y prefiero mencionarlo a callarme, o a quejarme a posteriori. Debería abrir una pregunta en Meta al respecto o sería considerado como influir en las elecciones? Quizá por defecto podrían responder a las preguntas del [cuestionario de las últimas elecciones](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4372/5481)?