# ¿Podrían (deberían) los candidatos a mod responder preguntas sobre moderación?

Tags: discusión

Debido a mi poca actividad en el stack, retroalimentada por la baja participación en meta (Hasta la fecha en 2022 tenemos 7 preguntas de meta, una media de una por mes) he llegado un poco tarde al anuncio de [la renuncia de Charlie como mod](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4457/5481) que abre un (y solo uno) nuevo puesto de mod para el que hay [elecciones](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4455/5481) (aunque estas elecciones empezaron el día 13 y la renuncia de Charlie no se explicó hasta el 17).

Actualmente hay dos candidatos, ambos con menos de 400 puntos de reputación y unos 10 posts en el stack. Entre lo escaso de su participación y lo desconectado que ando del stack (por lo que no conozco a usuarios más recientes), no puedo tomar una decisión informada sobre quién creo que sería un mejor moderador.

En el pasado hemos recogido preguntas para los candidatos a moderador <sup>1</sup>. ¿Sería posible que los candidatos a estas elecciones respondiesen algunas de estas preguntas para que podamos tener una opinión informada sobre qué estaríamos apoyando con nuestro voto? ¿Cuáles son los problemas que ven en el stack, qué visión tienen para el stack y qué ideas tienen para superar esos problemas y llevar al stack hacia su visión del mismo?

Aunque he dejado un comentario similar en [2022 Community Moderator Election](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4455/5481) y no estoy seguro de si el tiempo o el formato de las elecciones lo permitirán, creo que sería buena idea que los candidatos, además de nominarse respondiesen a algunas de estas preguntas.

La razón es que en el pasado [he realizado críticas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4399/5481) porque pensaba que las elecciones no habían servido para identificar a líderes de la comunidad y darles herramientas que le ayudasen a llevar a cabo su visión de lo que el stack podría llegar a ser, y algunas de las contrarréplicas a mis críticas eran no haber formulado mis críticas durante el proceso de elección.

Me gustaría elegir moderadores tipo "community leader" y no simples "human error handler", y si supiese algo acerca de los usuarios que se han nominado al puesto podría tomar una decisión informada.

---

1. Referencias

- [2020 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4372/5481)
- [2019 Pro Tem Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3170/5481)

Comment: Absolutamente de acuerdo.

Comment: De hecho se ha pasado de tener históricamente a dos o tres moderadores vinculados al sitio a tener ahora a uno solo, que es wimi. Dado que los dos candidatos no tienen ningún vínculo con Meta y apenas han interactuado en el sitio principal, me parece que vamos a sumar un "human error handler" en el mejor de los casos.

Comment: SE es un mar de contradicciones, en todo sentido, no solo el Spanish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A mí también me ha sorprendido que no haya habido un cuestionario esta vez. Normalmente, esto es organizado por los CMs. **Actualización:** parece que los CMs solo organizan el cuestionario en las elecciones completas, y no en las "pro-tempore". Básicamente, el 10 de mayo se decidió que habría una elección el 13 de junio, y después no ocurrió nada más hasta el día de la elección. No anuncié la elección antes porque no quería revelar la renuncia de Charlie antes de que lo hiciera él. Con lo del diseño de graduación, la verdad es que me distraje un poco del tema de la elección hasta que el 13 de junio de repente apareció.

Es claramente tarde, pero aún así he copiado el cuestionario de la elección de 2020 [aquí](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4461/24236) y espero que los dos candidatos [Efren](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/3?tab=election#post-40682) y [greuze](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/3?tab=election#post-40691) respondan al menos a algunas de las preguntas.