# 2022 Moderator Election Questionnaire

Tags: discusión, elecciones, moderadores

The [2022 moderator election](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) is live. It seems that, as this is a pro-tempore election, this time nobody from the CM team has organized the usual questionnaire. Although it is obviously quite late, I copy here the [questionnaire](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4383/24236) from 2020. It would be nice if the two candidates [Efren](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/3?tab=election#post-40682) and [greuze](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/3?tab=election#post-40691) answer at least some of the questions.

> 1. In your opinion, what do moderators do?
> 2. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
> 3. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?
> 4. How do you feel about low Meta participation? If you think it is a problem, how would you get more people to join Meta discussions? If you think it is not a problem, what other mechanisms do you intend to use to get input from the community on proposed policy changes, events, etc.?
> 5. Quite often Spanish.SE gets answers from unregistered users that are extremely short, just in the limit of "not an answer". These answers have their value, normally because they talk about the usage of some expression in the user's location. As a moderator you are quite likely to get some flags on these posts (some automatic from the Community user and some from normal users). How do you think such answers need to be handled?
> 6. In your opinion, what is the biggest problem/challenge Spanish Language Stack Exchange is currently facing? How would you propose to solve it?
> 7. What are your ideas to [engage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12023) users in the different activities of the stack (Meta participation, upvoting, participating in the review queues, chat, etc.)
> 8. For a long time, the site's graduation was a goal (or the main goal) for our community. Now that [we are no longer beta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3128), what do you think that should be the next milestone for our community (a shared goal across our community, that is kind of a [*big audacious hairy goal*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19161/5481)).  This could be rephrased as "What are this site's challenges and how do you plan to help empowering the community to work on them"?
> 9. From autumn 2019, the Stack Exchange community has faced several problems. Many mods have resigned (including two from Spanish.SE), many people disengaged and/or stopped participating in sites, etc. As a consequence, mod activities have slowed down and, in general, the network atmosphere is not as enthusiastic as it used to be. Taking all of this into account, why are you running for a mod position? What it is your motivation to serve the community in good faith, considering that you may face situations where you will be in a position where both Stack Exchange and the community will be pressing in different directions? / Spanish version: *Desde el otoño de 2019, la comunidad de Stack Exchange ha tenido bastantes problemas. Muchos moderadores de la red han dimitido (también en Spanish.SE), hay bastante gente que ha dejado los sitios o reducido su actividad de forma significativa, etc. Como consecuencia de ello, la actividad de moderación se ha reducido y, en general, el clima no es tan expansivo como en épocas anteriores. Conociendo todo esto, ¿por qué te presentas a moderador y con qué finalidad? ¿Qué te motiva a servir a la comunidad con buena fe, habida cuenta que puedes encontrarte en más de una ocasión en fuego cruzado (Stack Exchange por un lado, la comunidad por el otro)?*
> 10. What contribution(s) to Meta (no more than three examples) would you say best exemplify your prospective moderation style?

Comment: Pues [terminaron las elecciones](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4463/5481) y los candidatos o bien no vieron ni los post de Meta y los mensajes de la tertulia (tanto de Wimi como de Charlie) o no les ha dado a bien a los candidatos responder las preguntas. No sé si me preocupa más que los candidatos/nuevo mod no se pasen ni por Meta ni por la tertulia o que no les importe no responder a esta petición. Ambas situaciones dejan entrever algo distinto, pero ninguna es buena.

Comment: De acuerdo con lo que comentas, @Diego. También quiero poner de relieve el esfuerzo hecho por wimi durante el proceso: es muy de valorar tu empeño, wimi. Éxito para el nuevo equipo.

Comment: @Diego lo de la tertulia era un superping. En cualquier caso, ninguno de los dos candidatos ha visitado el sitio en los últimos 5 días. No espero grandes sorpresas, desgraciadamente.

Comment: @fedorqui gracias. A ver cómo se desarrolla la cosa...

Comment: De lo que estáis diciendo, no sé qué me parece peor...

Comment: Porqué intentan que parezca democracia cuando todo es un circo servicial?

Comment: @Diego Tengo respuestas a todo lo que comentas, pero al nivel actual de SE no creo les interese ni leerlas o tan siquiera que se insinúen 

Comment: Lo siento, tuve problemas de salud, ya veo que este sitio es muy exigente e intolerante, sobre todo sin preparar una eleccion y pretender que de un dia para el otro en un fin de semana alguien conteste un formulario, para un sitio que deberia ser para consultas y respuestas. No es un gobierno o la policia que requiere accion inmediata. Me alegro que no haya sido elegido.

Comment: Deberían leer esto primero antes de poner comentarios ofensivos sobre moderadores y asumir un montón de ideas negativas sobre las personas sin ningún fundamento, para justificar algo muy mal organizado: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/
Definitivamente, que alguien que quiera colaborar reciba tanta negatividad explica el estado de este sitio.

Comment: Pues @Efren, de ese mismo link que pones "As a moderator, your actions now represent the community, so you will be held to a higher standard of behavior". También, del enlace de la elección donde postulaste voluntariamente tu candidatura "criteria for mods is as follows: **patient and fair, leads by example**". Podemos discutir si las peticiones y expectativas de la comunidad son poco razonables, pero esa respuesta pasiva agresiva tildando a la comunidad de "exigente e intolerante" es precisamente el motivo por que el queremos conocer a los candidatos y su estilo de moderación antes de votar.

Comment: Añado que [la solicitud de responder estas preguntas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4460/5481) es también una crítica al proceso de elecciones (no a los candidatos ni una obligación). Los mods han intentado cumplir su función y atender como mejor han podido a la petición de la comunidad, haciendo un esfuerzo para poner las preguntas en un post en tiempo record y haciendo un par de superpings en La Tertulia como recordatorio. La suyo sería agradecer la cortesía y el esfuerzo y explicar que por desgracia no te has podido conectar en 5 días sin insultar a los que querías moderar.

Comment: But what do community moderators do? The short answer is, as little as possible!

Comment: @Efren yes, they do as little as possible. But when they have to do something, it obviously cannot wait 10 days. If offensive content stays on the site for 10 days, the site will be considered to have failed. So a moderator who visits the site once every 10 days is helpful only to a certain extent.