# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discusión, elecciones

[Moderator election #3](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/3) on Spanish Language has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: greuze]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Charlie, who will be stepping down as moderator:

[image: Charlie]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/3) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4973946666483712).

Comment: Please, if you're going to downvote this post, leave a comment or answer explaining why. We should celebrate that we've had an election with two volunteers and a new moderator has been appointed. I know we could have known them better as they have not answered the questionnaire. Nonetheless, congratulations to greuze and I wish them the best for the moderation tasks.

Comment: I downvoted this post. While we could/should celebrate that we had candidates (unlike [Moderator election: interest check](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4447/5481) a couple months back) it's obvious that [candidates either are not active in Meta/La Tertulia or did not care to respond to a community's request](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4461/5481). It's difficult to celebrate election results when the new mod has such a poor way to start and elections run this way. Hopefully this will change as they get into their new role. I wish the new mod and the stack the best.

Comment: Felicitaciones!!! Reciba un cordial saludo. @greuze

Comment: ¿Solo 67 votos en total? Uff !!!