¿Por qué hay tan pocos votos a las preguntas y respuestas?
Una de las razones podría ser la falta de suficientes visitantes. No obstante, me inclino por cierta mezquindad o falta de valoración a la hora de considerar el aporte de los miembros, lo que a su vez desalienta la participación. Me gustaría conocer el parecer de los demás.

No estoy seguro que sea mezquindad, pero en mi experiencia si ocurre que los hispanohablantes tienden a votar menos. En lo personal, me llevó mucho más esfuerzo en StackOverflow en español que en inglés llegar a un buen nivel de reputación y, a la fecha, aún son pocas las medallas de tags que tengo en el sitio en español comparado con el sitio en inglés. Si bien es cierto que tiene también mucho menos tráfico y es difícil comparar, me queda la sensación que quizás nuestra cultura de competencia tenga algo más de egoísmo o la envidia que en otras partes del mundo.

También me di cuenta de que las preguntas de gramática suelen ser las menos populares, como que al hablante es lo que menos le preocupa. O al menos no le preocupa entender el porqué es de una forma y no de otra.

Tráfico
Es la única respuesta a tu pregunta.
A partir de aquí:
Cómo generar tráfico
En estos momentos el sitio está en un "impasse productivo": solo tiene un moderador y no suele ser muy participativo. ¿Qué relación hay entre los moderadores y el tráfico? Creo que un gran porcentaje
1 - El tráfico se crea con la actividad del sitio, y sin moderación que actúe sobre las flags, es como jugar al tenis sin rival, todo solo va en una dirección, sin recepción ni respuesta. No existe ningún tipo de feed-back, lo que quita cualquier tipo de interés por el sitio.
2 - Existen modos de generar algún tipo de convocatoria al sitio, solo hay que ser un poco creativo y tener interés por ponerlo en marcha. Esto lo puede hacer tanto un usuario, como un moderador actuando como usuario. Si bien el atraer usuarios no es la funcionalidad de un moderador, bien podría decirse que éste es un "usuario destacado", por lo que su convocatoria puede llegar a ser de mayor interés. Un usuario normal puede hacerlo a través de preguntas, comentarios y chat, pero volvemos al punto 1, sin moderación es un salto al vacío.
3 - Fomentar la participación de usuarios activos. Esto también lo puede hacer un usuario normal, pero la actuación de un moderador da mayor confianza. Del mismo modo, intentar frenar el avance de usuarios conflictivos. Afortunadamente el sitio no cuenta con muchos de estos últimos, pero los pocos que hay suelen hacerse notar más que el resto. Esto no solo desmotiva sino que también incrementa la desazón y en consecuencia la falta de interés por participar e incluso retornar.

También hay que entender que SE a nivel general no es lo mismo que hace años, solo con ver las valoraciones de las preguntas y respuestas de hace diez años de cualquier sitio con las actuales da la pauta que algo está yendo a la baja, llámese AI, exceso de info, o existencia de otros canales.

Toda la confianza puesta en el siguiente moderador y los tres puntos anteriores como básicos a tener en cuenta para la votación:

¿Cuál es tu compromiso con el sitio?
¿Qué acciones crees son las conveniente para generar tráfico?
¿Cómo fomentarías la participación de usuarios activos?


Necesitamos alentar a los usuarios a publicar en español. https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4491/announcing-a-graduation-election-for-2024#comment7376_4491

¡Quizás haya tan pocos votos para preguntas y respuestas porque el texto que se muestra al pasar el mouse sobre los botones de votación está en inglés!
