# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discusión, elecciones

Spanish Language's [first moderator election](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close and the new moderator is:

[image: Charlie]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with him as he learns the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Flimzy and Joze who will be stepping down as moderator.

This is a [special election](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3123/announcing-a-pro-tempore-moderator-election), and that is why we were able to call the election without a vote.

Comment: Congratulations to both! Let's give our best to Spanish.se. Walen and Charlie, please feel free to ping us with any questions

Comment: Jon: Well, I'm a little late to the party!  I've been moving house and I haven't looked at any of the other election materials yet.  I thought I still had time to get up to speed, because there is a notification in the Meta box (right-hand sidebar) that says, "2019 Community Moderator Election ends in 8 days."  I thought I still had time to play catch-up.  (That notification is still there, by the way.)  This thread is about as confusing as the recent news reports out of the UK.  At any rate, Charlie and walen - I would like to thank you for stepping up to the plate.

Answer (score 1):

Why is nothing displayed on the election summary for 2019 (see below) even though Charlie was a candidate that became a mod?

[image]

Furthermore, it says "2 candidates" but only one shows up here:

[image]

Comment: Since there was as many candidates as slots, we didn’t run the election. It’s an unusual case so things could very well be off. Since I’m no longer an employee, there’s nothing I can do anyway. 

Comment: But we can't see who the other candidate was?

Comment: I believe the other candidate no longer has an account. You can look at the edit history of the announcement. But when former moderator accounts are deleted odd things happen.

Comment: @JonEricson there is (and was, yesterday) a discussion explaining this in [The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8995165#8995165).