# Election shown as ongoing in the right sidebar

Tags: soporte, estado-completado, elecciones

Our first election process ended yesterday. Congratulations, Charlie!!

However, the right sidebar still shows the event for the election, and worse of all it is shown as still ongoing:

[image]

Some users have already expressed that they feel confused about this. Could you please fix it? Thanks!*

<sub><sub>* Yeah yeah I know I'm not supposed to end with "thanks".</sub></sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Pro Tem Elections are a manual adaptation of the normal elections, it was scheduled to last for two weeks: one for nominations and one for voting. The Community user automatically created an event that lasted from September 9, 2019, until September 24.

Since there weren't more candidates than available positions, the voting was not necessary so it ended with the automatic [2019 Community Moderator Election Results](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3181/1674).

I have edited the event so it finishes now.