# Sobre el nuevo Código de Conducta y otros eventos recientes de la red

Tags: discusión, código-de-conducta

No suelo participar en otros stacks de la red y prácticamente todo mi tiempo en este stack se va a tareas de moderación (habréis notado que posteo cada vez menos preguntas, y ya casi nunca respuestas...). Por eso, habéis sido otros usuarios los que habéis llamado mi atención sobre [un asunto que está sacudiendo la red de Stack Exchange](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/31604/5481).

He tratado de enterarme de qué va la cosa, pero no hay mucha información. La mayor parte de los posts repiten cosas dichas en otros posts en un stack diferente. Falta información de las fuentes oficiales.

La mayor parte de la controversia (y malestar) parece centrarse en dos puntos principales:

- Un nuevo Código de Conducta, que parece contener ciertas normas sobre el uso de pronombres —específicamente, cómo dirigirse a los usuarios cuando estos solicitan un uso particular de pronombres. **Nadie ha visto este nuevo Código de Conducta todavía**.
- La gestión de Stack Overflow Inc. de un caso que ha dado a conocer que es posible que ya se esté aplicando este nuevo Código de Conducta que no se nos ha dado a conocer y su postura ante la reacción de parte de los usuarios.

Por esta razón, ayer por la noche escribí a título personal a los *Community Managers* agregando en copia al resto del equipo de moderación de Spanish.SE.

El objetivo es conocer de primera mano el contenido de este código de conducta, y poder estudiar cómo puede afectar al stack y poder tomar **una posición informada** sobre el mismo.

No creo que me respondan pronto. Primero, porque no suelen hacerlo, y segundo, porque parece que tienen otras prioridades entre manos ahora mismo.

Aun así, quiero hacer público que hemos preguntado formalmente a las fuentes oficiales qué dice realmente este objeto de controversia, primero para que podamos tomar una decisión informada sobre el mismo. Segundo,  para recordar a la comunidad que no sabemos qué cosas desconocemos sobre este asunto. **Toca esperar**. Los mods haremos nuestro mejor esfuerzo y, en la medida de lo posible, ayudaremos a la comunidad a entender qué está sucediendo a medida que dispongamos de información.

Una última reflexión: Esta es una comunidad en la que da gusto participar. Durante las recientes elecciones a moderador hemos repetido que nosotros los moderadores siempre intentamos liderar con el ejemplo, pero hay que destacar que la comunidad en general ha estado también siempre a la altura, y cada uno de vosotros ha hecho su mejor esfuerzo para hacer de esta comunidad lo que es.

Que no sea distinto ahora. Si decidís intercambiar opiniones al respecto de esta situación con otros miembros de la red, recordad por favor que de momento no parece que tengamos todas las piezas de puzzle, así que sed cuidadosos al juzgar. Recordad también que aquellos que tienen opiniones contrarias a las vuestras sobre algunos de estos temas conflictivos pueden compartir vuestros objetivos, y simplemente difieren sobre el método. Intentad entender qué motiva a los demás, antes de decirles por qué se equivocan.

Sed buenos. [Be nice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

Comment: Gracias, Diego, y Fedorqui y Charlie, bien hecho. // *Nadie ha visto este nuevo Código de Conducta todavía* - ¿Quieres decir que un comité de directores habrá redactado algo pero no han difundido su propuesta a los moderadores comunes y corrientes, ni mucho menos a la comunidad? // Perdón, no entiendo tu segundo bullet, a lo mejor sobra o falta una palabra.

Comment: Vi en SE Meta que @fedorqui se puso en estatus suspendido por ahora.  Menciono esto a manera de FYI a todos.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/287826

Comment: [Yo también permaneceré inactivo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334127/356575) hasta que se clarifique por parte de SE Inc el nuevo Código de Conducta. Los moderadores de Spanish.se hemos contactado a los community managers en buena fe para poder desarrollar una opinión informada que nos permita servir mejor a esta comunidad. Si los CM o SE Inc no quieren darnos lo que necesitamos para desarrollar esta tarea, no seguiré dedicando de manera voluntaria mi tiempo hasta que lo hagan. Ayudaré en la moderación de temas urgentes y ofreceré consejo, pero no gestionaré flags, peticiones, etc.

Comment: Diego, thank you for standing up to be counted.

Comment: I thought your post on MSE was exemplary. The issue of people working in a language with which they are not 100% familiar is one which is often ignored by users on technical sites. I doubt anyone will take any notice but good to see it raised.

Comment: Yo acabo de tener una respuesta borrada por un administrador que no pertenece a Spanish.SE, sin consultación, sin votos, ni nada de ná.  Dado todo lo visto y leído, creo que también voy a darme de baja una temporada, si no definitivamente.

Comment: @guifa Mi recomendación como usuario es publicar en meta, con pantallazo incluido, y preguntar por qué, aparentemente, **alguien que no modera en Spanish.Se está moderando Spanish.Se**. Y que de explicaciones (si piensas que te deben explicaciones) quien deba darlas.

Comment: Solo para confirmar, el JNat como moderador, como tiene reputación 101, sería algo «nuevo»?

Comment: @guifa si haces click en "users" (en el margen izquierdo) y luego en la pestaña de "mods" te aparecen los que son [mods de Spanis.Se](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) (fedorqui y yo estamos inactivos como indicamos arriba en los comentarios y posts enlazados). Puedes buscar usuarios también por nombre de perfil. [Jnat](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8740/jnat?tab=profile) no es un mod de Spanish.se. Hace poco JNat anunció las [elecciones a mod pro tempore](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3123/5481). Su rol o privilegios exactos los ignoro.

Comment: @Diego pues al final rechazan contestar, además cerraron la pregunta.  Dice un moderador por allí que era por la palabrota de la traududucción de aparente001, lo he quitado pero aún queda cerrado.  Yo no puedo votar por reabrirlo porque fue un moderador.

Comment: JNat, como aparece en su perfil, es trabajador de SO y tiene el poder de vestirse el rombo en cualquier stack y usar los mismos poderes que los moderadores. Se vienen malos tiempos me parece

Comment: @guifa, cúal han cerrado? [Deletion by someone outside the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334185/356575)? En ese stack casi no tengo privilegios, así que no puedo ver el historial del post. Cuando dicen que es "por la palabrota de Aparente", es por algo que hay en tu post o en el de otro? No me cuadra esa explicación, ni la que propone un comentario diciendo que, debido a la masiva "huelga" de mods, los empleados de SE están realizando estas tareas de moderación en distintos sitios.

Comment: Por si alguien los encuentra interesantes, aquí dejo unos cuantos posts de MetaSe: [An open letter on the state of curation and moderation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334015/356575). [Are there any objections to using singular they for everyone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334203/356575) que incluye [English as a foreign language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334220/356575) en una respuesta. Es evidente que toda la comunidad tiene ganas de hablar de este tema. SE inc. sigue en silencio.

Comment: Because there’re a lot of beginning Spanish speakers on this site (*cough* me *cough*), do you think you could please provide a good English translation, please? Thanks!

Comment: @Stormblessed - Sorry, I only just noticed your comment.  Only two and a half months late!  At any rate, I don't think there's anything earth-shattering here that would be worth translating.  Otherwise, I would.  I would think that the material here is more or less equivalent to what's available at, for example, [The Story So Far](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334399/287826).

Answer (score 4):

Respuesta oficial (hasta la fecha)

- Sara Chipps ♦ - [An Update to our Community and an Apology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334248/356575) <sub>3 de octubre 2019</sub>
- David Fullerton ♦ - [An apology to our community, and next steps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334551/356575) <sub>6 de octubre 2019</sub>
- Sara Chipps ♦ - [Iterating on Inclusion](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/10/iterating-on-inclusion/) <sub>10 octubre 2019</sub>
- New [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) <sub>10 octubre 2019</sub>
- <s>Cesar M. ♦ - Official [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334900/287826) on gender pronouns and Code of Conduct changes <sub>10 octubre 2019</sub></s> <sub>invalidado por la siguiente publicación</sub>
- Catija♦ - [What does the Code of Conduct say about pronouns?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336364/356575) <sub>23 octubre 2019</sub>

  Esta última publicación contiene una parte relevante para sitios como el nuestro, en el que se usa un idioma diferente del inglés:

  > 6. How does this apply to languages other than English?
  >
  > While these specific requirements around pronoun usage apply only to the English language, the goal of being inclusive and respectful of all genders applies to all our communities

---

Noticia: Monica y SE llegaron a un acuerdo el 23 de diciembre.

Sara Chipps ♦ - [Update: an agreement with Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340906/356575) <sub>25 de diciembre 2019</sub>

https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users

Comment: Y en apenas 5 horas tiene 400 downvotes y 38 respuestas ...

Comment: Para dar más cifras, en un edit del post con link a [Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/356575) se cuentan, de momento 16 mods que han dimitido (14 en realidad, pues Cellio fue _cesada_ y uno ha pedido ser readmitido tras dimitir) y 24 que han cesado acción de alguna manera (suspended activity), algunos en múltiples stacks que moderaban. Hay que tener en cuenta que esos números son de todos los stacks, pero aún así es para fliparlo.

Comment: Con respeto a la nueva disculpa -- *enhorabuena*.

Comment: @walen - Yo apoyaría esta propuesta si la quieres hacer en Meta SE.

Comment: [SE Inc. Director of Public Q&A retweets bad-faith, misrepresentative tweet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335173/356575)

Comment: A día de hoy el nuevo CoC y su [FAQ asociada](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334900/356575) tienen un balance de votros de -1634. En [Does the company want to enforce CoC irrespective of the backlash it received?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335893/356575) se indica que [tal vez se cambie el FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335894/356575), que no sé hasta qué punto indica un cambio en el CoC.

Comment: En [What is Stack Exchange going to do to prevent further weaponization of the Code of Conduct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335939/356575) se indica que "StackExchange is working on addressing these issues and have committed to doing so publicly by Tuesday, October 22th" (fuente: [A letter from moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335868/356575))

Comment: Añado [Monica's situation continues unresolved, is SE hoping the problem just goes away?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335508/356575), que creo que no lo he puesto todavía. **Con todo el jaleo este de los pronombres pasa a segundo plano el trato a Monica Cellio**. No solo las formas de su "despido" y el hecho de que, aparentemente, evaluasen su conducta de acuerdo a un CoC que de momento no había sido hecho público, sino también el hecho de que con sus acciones SE difamó a esta usuaria sin darle oportunidad de defenderse de aquello que SE dijo que fue la causa de sus destitución

Comment: @Diego - Estaría bien que hicieras una respuesta compilando estos enlaces.

Comment: @aparente001 Ya, pero es que es fácil identificar posts relevantes que vienen de las fuentes oficiales. Todos los otros que pongo son de interés subjetivo/personal. Además quiero separar lo que afecta a este stack de forma directa (el CoC - nuevas normas) de otras cosas relacionadas con esta situación (el indignante trato a Monica no afecta directamente a esta comunidad). La idea era facilitar que los usuarios de Spanish pudiesen seguir los acontecimientos clave, pero no quiero crear otra respuesta para documentar o anunciar posts que se discuten en meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @aparente001 Aparte, creo que la gente ya está o bien emocionalmente cansada, en fase de aceptación o satisfecha con la resolución a la que se ha llegado. Viendo que nadie tiene especial interés en seguir comentado sobre estos asuntos, los problemas por resolver y los nuevos que vendrán (y mucho menos protestando activamente), prefiero no convertirme en un agitador (a base de añadir estos posts de Meta que ponen a SE un poco contra las cuerdas). Creo que ya estoy presionando un poco los límites en Meta en Spanish.se y tengo que elegir mis batallas.

Comment: @aparente001 Aunque claro, mención especial tendría [Stack Overflow is doing me ongoing harm; it's time to fix it!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336526/356575) publicado sobre la propia Monica Cellio sobre todo este asunto. No sé qué hará al final SE con ella y su situación. Mucho me temo que el daño a su reputación y salud ya está hecho. Debido al tiempo que ha ido pasando y/o al hecho de añadir muchos puntos a la FAQ y clarificar (o microgestionar) lo de los pronombres, parece que para muchos este tema ya no es importante y se puede dejar estar :-(

Comment: @Diego - Nos afecta a todos directamente porque perdimos un moderador.  Pero de todos modos acepto tu preferencia, claro está.

Comment: Jon Ericson se va y Shog9 y Robert Cartaino han sido despedidos :O

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' JO.DER. Lo de Jon no lo había visto. Lo de los otros dos sí. Acaba de publicar en Meta? Lo que haya pasado de verdad con Shog9 y Robert Cartaino no lo sabremos nunca, pero el mensaje que pusieron en meta de que con esto está ["investing in the community and ensuring that it has a seat"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342045/356575) parece casi una burla

Comment: [Change in roles for Jon Ericson (leaving SE)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342424/356575) "I made this decision in December and it's not correlated with the recent CM team changes. These are just an unfortunate coincidence"

Comment: Luego en su blog escribió [Why I left Stack Overflow](https://jlericson.com/2020/01/17/leaving_stack.html) diciendo cosas como _In September and October, a series of events demonstrated that leadership within the company neither understood community management nor was willing to learn_. Cuántas pérdidas sensibles y qué pena ver cómo diverge el camino de SE del camino de los usuarios...

Comment: Del camino de los usuarios y del camino de empleados valiosos. Suena a cliché, pero es que hay gente que quiere contratar gente inteligente y luego decirles lo que tienen que hacer y que pensar. Si tienes gente inteligente y valiosa (sobre todo como estos últimos que han estado casi desde el principio en la compañía) lo suyo es escucharles y usar su experiencia para dirigir el negocio. A saber qué movidas han debido de estar teniendo en la compañía para provocar este tipo de reacción en gente que llevada 8 años dentro. Lo de "nor was willing to learn" es lo peor de todo. Qué frustrante.

Comment: [Se va Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356545/209901) :/

Comment: No sé hasta qué punto la marcha de Tim Post está relacionada con todo lo demás. Supongo que no está relacionada de manera directa con los eventos que motivaron este hilo pero sí de manera indirecta. Curioso que publique Machavity (tu post enlazado) y tenga 180 upvotes. Se lo cierran como duplicado que uno que Sara Chipps crea **después** ("Timing was a bit unfortunate", dice Tinkerbell) y el de Chipps tiene solo 20 upvotes. Yo a veces no entiendo a esta gente. Pero claro, como dice alguien por ahí "*instead of giving a good tribute to the creators of all of this, we are making them run away*".

Comment: @Diego no podremos saber qué lo motivó, pero el ambiente tóxico del sitio en el último año seguramente tuvo mucho que ver (el comentario que mencionas, por cierto, es mío!). A mí me apena que casi toda la comunidad tenga bastante identificado el origen del problema (los votos así lo reflejan) y que sea el resto de gente la que se acabe yendo...

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' `el comentario que mencionas, por cierto, es mío!` Lo sé, lo sé. Es que como cada vez que escribo uso los 600 caracteres, no me quedaba para el emoticono del guiño. Igual Tim hace luego como en su tiempo hizo Jon y escribe su propio "Why I left Stack Overflow" y nos los explica de primera mano.

Answer (score 1):

Otras publicaciones relevantes:

- [Stack Overflow is doing me ongoing harm; it's time to fix it!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336526/209901), escrito por Monica Cellio (moderadora a la que se quitó tal condición y cuyas acciones fueron cuestionadas en prensa por parte de una empleada importante de Stack Overflow)
- [How should the new pronoun policy be applied to Spanish language?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339133/209901), consultando cómo aplicará la política de pronombres a los sitios donde se usa el castellano.