# Pido permiso para usar @ en los adjetivos de mis posts cuando hablo de mí mism@

Tags: discusión, soporte

Cuando escribo en inglés en SE, mi pronombre es "they."  Aquí en Spanish.SE, tengo que hacer formulaciones rebuscadas ("Siento cierta confusión" en lugar de "Me siento confundid_"), o bien recurrir al inglés.  Pues ya me cansé de eso, y quisiera empezar a utilizar el símbolo @ ("Me siento confundid@").

En discusiones previas aquí en Meta, ha habido algunas objeciones a la idea de usar "@" en general en Spanish.SE.  Pues ahorita no estoy buscando una decisión generalizada, nomás quiero saber si YO puedo usar este símbolo, por lo pronto, en lo que YO escribo acá en mis posts y comentarios.  (Más adelante, si se concuerda una solución generalizada para el sitio, estoy dispuest@ a cambiar mi forma de escribir los adjetivos que uso para describirme a mí.)

Comment: SO Inc nos tiene en un _impasse_ entre el mundo anterior en el que cada cual utilizaba el que quería bajo el genérico paraguas del _Be nice_ y el actual estado de las cosas en el que no debe ofenderse a nadie, sin que haya sido excesivamente detallado y aún menos en el caso de lenguas que no son el inglés. En cualquier caso, no perdamos el foco: cada cual debe sentirse cómodo en el sitio sin incomodar a los otros. No creo que a nadie le incomode tu uso de _@_ y es bueno que te ayude a ti, por lo que a mí me parece perfecto. Otra cosa es que deseara que la moda del _@_ hubiera muerto ya :D

Comment: No es solo que SO Inc nos tenga en este _impasse_ permanente... es el _porqué_ y el _cómo_. Tras sacrificar a [Mónica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336526/356575) en el altar, las motivaciones de este nuevo reglamento quedaron cuestionadas, y [señalar la puerta de salida](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335173/356575) a quien no comulgase con las nuevas normas no ayudó precisamente a motivar a la gente a querer seguir trabajando en hacer un SE mejor. Creo que lejos de mejorar el _Be Nice_ nos pusieron a unos contra otros en una especie de caza de brujas.

Comment: @fedorqui - Gracias por comentar.  No entendí tu última frase.

Comment: @Diego - También, gracias por comentar.  Todo lo que dijiste del conflicto que ha habido y el mal comportamiento de ciertos partidarios es cierto; pero ¿qué tiene que ver con mi pregunta?

Comment: Aparente: que a mí personalmente no me gusta nada la moda de poner @ al final de las palabras. Se puso muy de moda con la popularización de Internet, tanto que resultó un poco saturante. Prefiero otras opciones, pero si esta te gusta a ti, no seré yo quien te pida usar otra.

Comment: @fedorqui - Gracias por aclarar.  Vamos a imaginar que tengas un primo o sobrino a algo que llegue a darse cuenta que ni *él* ni *ella* le queda bien, y te pide consejo.  ¿Qué le sugerirías?

Comment: @aparente001 Yo apostaría por el tradicional _amigo/a_, _confundido/a_, etc. Pero como dije, es mi opinión y en este caso preguntar sobre tu forma de identificarte contigo mismo/a, que es algo que solo te corresponde a ti decidir.

Comment: @aparente001 Nada. Mi comentario de más arriba es sobre el "_impasse_ permanente" que menciona Fedorqui en su comentario anterior, no sobre tu pregunta. Clarifico que pienso que al hacer nuevas normas, que incluyen medidas tan punitivas como la sufrida por Mónica Cellio, y desdecirse sin admitir que habían hecho mal las cosas, dejándonos con un CoC ambiguo y que se contradice, sin claras normas para el problema que pretendían resolver (pero dando a entender serias consecuencias de no acatarlo) ha empeorado el "Be Nice", y lo que antes era fácil y nos salía solo, ahora es complicado y punitivo.

Comment: Me estoy dando cuenta de que esta pregunta solo trata a medias la cuestión. Has pedido permiso para usar la @, los demás hemos respondido y la idea general es que lo hagas si eso es lo que quieres. Pero falta la otra mitad de la cuestión, que es: acogiéndote al nuevo CoC, ¿cómo deseas que los demás usemos el lenguaje cuando hablemos de ti? ¿O prefieres dejar eso a la libre elección de cada uno?

Comment: @Charlie - Yo ni sé todavía cómo voy a manejar esto en mi propia escritura.  Estoy en una fase de probar diferentes opciones y ver qué funciona bien, qué no funciona tan bien, y espero que los demás se permitan un tiempo de experimentar también.  Si me permiten actuar aquí sin tener que ser ni ella ni él, quedaré c̶o̶n̶t̶e̶n̶t̶@̶  conforme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Independientemente de hasta qué punto estemos de acuerdo con las distintas formas de hablar, me parece excesivo que una persona tenga que pedir permiso para utilizar una cierta forma de referirse a *sí misma*.

Cada uno tiene libertad para decidir como habla de sí mismo, y en mi opinión esto aplica antes y después del cambio en el Código de Conducta (CoC). Tal como yo lo veo, todos los cambios en el CoC están relacionados con cómo referirse a *otros usuarios*.

Yo (al menos de momento) uso el masculino genérico para referirme a grupos genéricos en la manera que indica la RAE. Pero por supuesto, aparente001 puede usar la forma que mas cómoda le resulte para referirse a sí mism@, y (aunque entiendo que en esta última frase habrá más diferencia de opiniones) a mí tampoco me cuesta demasiado esfuerzo usar una forma diferente cuando me refiero a aparente001.

Comment: +1 por puro sentido común :)

Answer (score 3):

Yo ya expuse en su día mi objeción al uso de la @ por las dificultades técnicas que plantea para las personas ciegas, y porque en general me provoca confusión a la hora de tratar de leer en voz alta el texto. Como usuario del sitio te pediría que tiraras por otra opción, como puede ser el uso de "elle" (por nuestra parte) y "dispueste", "cansade" (por tu parte), que no plantean las dificultades mencionadas. Como moderador, en cambio, no pienso imponer aquí ningún estilo particular de redacción, más allá de lo que me obligue SO, Inc. Como el tema del español aún no está resuelto, puedes usar el estilo que más te convenga. Si quieres usar la @, por mí adelante.

Por cierto, iba a decir que yo te considero el embajador de la inclusividad en nuestro sitio, pero ¿"embajador" te parece bien? ¿O mejor uso "embajador@"? Es una pregunta seria, es que me resulta rara esa @ porque parece que el masculino es "embajadoro", ¿cómo hacemos para no determinar los sustantivos en los que el femenino añade la "a" al final en vez de sustituir una "o"? Sinceramente, "embajadore" me genera menos conflicto, pero insisto, lo hacemos como tú quieras.

Comment: A mi aviso, *embajador, músico* y *científico* sirven para todos, hombres y mujeres.  (Opinión personal.) // "Elle" no está mal.  Hmm.  Me pregunto cómo los demás pronuncian @ (ejemplo *latin@*).  Voy a preguntar (más tarde).

Comment: I think the point about people using screen readers is a good one and seems like an argument for using -x or -e which I assume they would find easier.

Comment: Ya expuse por allí que lo de los lectores de pantalla no me parecía tan relevante... para luego comprobar que ni siquiera Google Translate entiende bien la @. No sé qué proporción lo usa en comparación con los que no lo usen y no entiendan estos neologismos (pienso en mi padre). En cualquier caso, comparto la idea expuesta de que use el estilo que mejor le resulte

Answer (score 0):

Por mi puedes usar la arroba. Yo no creo que su uso sea correcto para ese fin, pero entiendo por qué lo pides y agradezco que hayas hecho el gesto de anunciarlo y valorar lo que piensa la comunidad.

Personalmente, como ya he explicado en [otras contribuciones](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3232/5481), yo no soy partidario ni de las formas que usan "@", "-x" y "e", ni de los neopronombres tipo "elle". Creo que no resuelven realmente el problema que pretenden resolver, complican el habla hasta el punto de la confusión o inviabilidad y están cargados de connotaciones políticas e ideológicas.

Para mi, el [intentar no especificar un género](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23963/5481), le obliga a uno necesariamente a esos incómodos circunloquios. Por otro lado, debido a ciertas restricciones del stack (como la limitación de caracteres en los comentarios), entiendo que usar "Siento cierta confusión" en lugar de "Me siento confundid_" puede hacer que en ocasiones el texto sea demasiado largo y por lo tanto inválido (o tendrías que postear múltiples comentarios. En definitiva, poco práctico).

No se me escapa tampoco la ironía o contradicción de admitir este tipo de artificios en un sitio que es precisamente sobre el lenguaje, y donde aspiramos a ayudar a otros a hablar con la mayor corrección posible explicándoles las normas del lenguaje, pero entiendo que esta es un petición que se hace de buena fe para resolver un problema o situación personal, y no una imposición o exigencia para forzar a la gente a hablar de determinada manera.

Continuando con la discusión de [Should I avoid editing the forms including “@”, “x” and “-e” when/if seen in posts?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3233/5481) **yo me comprometo a no editar este tipo de formas, aunque no las considere correctas**, cuando las vea en posts.

Aun así, creo que su uso debería ser considerado en el stack como informal y un "mal necesario" (como no poner los acentos o admitir alguna falta de ortografía cuando escribes en un teclado que no te lo poner fácil, porque no tiene acentos o estás restringido por el teléfono móvil) y nunca como una forma correcta.

Creo que el uso de estos artificios, en la medida de lo posible, debería ser evitado (limitándolo a los comentarios, que tienen restricción de número de caracteres).

---

Pregunta del stack relevante: [Is the use of @ instead of 'a' or 'o' in order to refer to both masculine and femenine accepted?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/342/5481)

> Debe tenerse en cuenta que la arroba no es un signo lingüístico y, por ello, **su uso en estos casos es inadmisible desde el punto de vista normativo**; a esto se añade la **imposibilidad de aplicar esta fórmula integradora en muchos casos sin dar lugar a graves inconsistencias**, como ocurre en Día del niñ@, donde la contracción "del" solo es válida para el masculino niño

Comment: El principal inconveniente de los circunloquios (muy apto el término!) es el tiempo que lleva encontrar soluciones, y el tiempo que lleva suprimir las expresiones más normales. // Me siento un poco triste al ver el término "problema" en este contexto.  Solo es problema si los demás lo ven así.  No debería ser problema, a mi aviso.  Cuando leo a George Bernard Shaw, veo que en el tiempo de Shaw, gente de mucho estudio, y supuestamente de buena voluntad, hablaba con frecuencia del "problema de la mujer."  Sabemos ahora que el problema no era de la mujer, era de los que no aceptaban ...

Comment: ... plenamente a la mujer en la sociedad. Aunque sienta un poco de tristeza, no me siento ofendid_ (estoy probando otra idea), porque te conozco y sé que tienes buenas intenciones; también entiendo que estas cosas son nuevas y lleva tiempo entenderlas y lleva tiempo acostumbrarse a estas ideas.

Comment: Entiendo lo que comentas de la "ironía" de la situación, pero si hay algo que he aprendido en estos años es que el lenguaje es lo que nosotros hacemos de él, y que la RAE simplemente atestigua cómo lo usamos. De hecho hasta la RAE ha reconocido que lo de la "bolaspa" para indicar ejemplos erróneos fue un error, valga la redundancia, porque cualquier "error" puede convertirse en norma con el paso del tiempo. Sé que usar la "@" o la "e" o cualquier otra cosa no es gramatical... ahora. Pero ¿podría llegar a serlo en el futuro?

Comment: Sí, cierto que la RAE documenta cómo hablamos... pero es que yo no hablo así, me lo imponen (y todos sabemos lo que ha pasado hace muy poco en los stacks con el CoC y sus revisiones, que encima terminaron dejando de forma ambigua y/o contradictoria). Para que todo esto llegase a ser gramatical tendría que estar bien pensado (ya que es artificial en lugar de evolucionar de forma natural). Un ejemplo (sin ánimo de ofender): fíjate como en tu post estos artificios no te resuelven el problema con el artículo que necesitarías para "embajador@". Como ñapa informal, sí. Como norma gramatical, no.

Comment: +1 a la respuesta (de hecho le di hace un par de días). Es bueno el punto de que un sitio sobre el idioma debería aspirar a utilizarlo bien. En todo caso, parece que en este caso pesa más el cómo se siente aparente y creo (como ya dices tú) que aceptarlo así es mejor que imponer decirlo de otra forma que le/la incomode. En cualquier caso, me irrita que SO Inc haya abierto este debate de una forma tan chapucera y nos haya dejado _a medias_, enfrentándonos entre nosotros a la espera de ver qué deciden.

Comment: @fedorqui - Mira, SO Inc no nos ha dado ningún plazo concreto.  Yo pienso que nosotros mismos podemos ir explorando las opciones, de cómo implementar el respeto a la diversidad de género en nuestro sitio.  Así estaremos mejor ubicados para influir sobre las decisiones que tome la compañía (o una nueva organización sin fin de lucro, que yo espero que se establezca durante 2020).  Incluso, si queremos señalar la pauta, nos conviene probar y considerar muchas opciones, para luego poder dar nuestras recomendaciones.  Es cierto que ahorita la compañía no parece tener mucho interés en ...

Comment: ... las opiniones de la comunidad, pero los razonables somos mucho más numerosos que los no razonables, y no me rindo todavía. // Yo planteé esta pregunta (¿puedo usar @?) porque sabía que hay mucha opinión en contra aquí en nuestro sitio; pero a través de las respuestas y comentarios aquí he recibido más ideas y sugerencias, y tengo ganas de probar varias cosas, y de ver los experimentos que hagan los demás también.  Por ahora, tenemos casi toda la autonomía que podríamos desear aquí en Spanish.SE, para descubrir nuestro camino preferido.