# New style for quotes (bug or new feature): is it to stay?

Tags: discusión, soporte, interfaz-de-usuario

Haciendo hoy [una pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/33221/5481) he visto que el estilo de la cita era distinto. Veo también que la interfaz gráfica del sitio es un poco distinta aquí y allá y entiendo que esto un cambio anunciado y deseado y no un fallo.

Si embargo a mi me gusta un poco menos, porque el bloque de la cita no queda tan bien delimitado.

[image]

De haber suficiente interés en mantener el estilo antiguo y no el nuevo, ¿podría solicitarse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se ha venido anunciando en Meta.SE, en concreto en [Some improvements to blockquotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343919/209901).

A mí particularmente no me gusta tampoco pues reduce la visibilidad de los bloques de citación que tanto utilizamos en nuestro sitio para referenciar entradas de diccionario o fragmentos de texto.

Dudo que pueda solicitarse un cambio solo para nosotros, pues la tendencia de SE es de uniformizar los sitios. Lo que veo más plausible es hacer campaña en Meta.SE para que se añada contraste. Contad con mi voto, que por ejemplo ya he dado a [Please revert the quote background from white to yellow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344874/209901)

Comment: Pues vaya "improvement". Es esto en lo que está invirtiendo recursos esta compañía después del [incidente con Monica Cellio](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3207/5481), la pésima gestión y perder recursos como  Shog9 y [Jon Ericson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342424/356575)? Pues vaya.

Comment: @Diego sí, para sitios como el nuestro la pérdida es bastante grande.

Comment: @Diego parece que ahora se ve mucho mejor, [han anunciado cambios](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353446/209901) que a mí personalmente me gustan mucho. La citación se ve mucho más elegante.