# 2020 Moderator Election - We need more candidates!

Tags: discusión, elecciones

The [nomination period for the 2020 election](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/2) was scheduled to end in 30 minutes. However, in order for the election to proceed, we need to have *at least* candidates that aren't the only current moderator — given that, and [as mentioned in the original announcement](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4364/8740), we have extended the deadline for nominations for an additional seven days.

We need leadership to come from within this community, the election can't move forward unless someone wants to take on the responsibility. Did you consider nominating but decided not to for some reason? Now would be a great time to reconsider!

Comment: Has Monica been restored as a mod? If so, I'll throw in my hat.

Comment: @user0721090601 (apreciado Guifa) hasta donde yo sé, no ha sido restituida. Lo último que recuerdo es que le dijeron que si quería volver a ser mod que [lo solicitase según las nuevas normas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340906). Yo en su momento dejé de leer todos los post relevantes al tema y no estoy al día. Espero que alguien lo pueda aclararlo mejor que yo. Creo que Monica Cellio y otros usuarios de Stack Exchange han fundado su propio sitio de Q&A, [Codidact](https://codidact.org/) - de momento creo que no tienen "stack" de Español - por lo que no creo que se llegase a una solución.

Comment: @Diego Monica Cellio [dejó la comunidad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342950/209901), o más bien la echaron: _I write this post with tears literally in my eyes.

Though it pains me deeply to leave my communities, especially Mi Yodeya which I cherish and have helped build for close to nine years, I have decided I must leave the Stack Exchange network_. Triste forma de echar una de las personas más valiosas que ha tenido esta red (y lo mismo con Shog, Robert Cartaino y tantos otros).

Comment: @user0721090601 (siguiendo el comentario de Diego) veo que Codidact ya tiene sitio de Lingüística: https://languages.codidact.com

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Fíjate, ya hasta se me había olvidado que gente como Jon Ericson o Shog9 quedaron como _daños colaterales_ de todo el incidente. Me acordaba de los delirantes posts de "disculpas" de Sara Chipps, el CEO y [todo eso](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3211/5481), pero ignoraba si la cosa había cambiado o evolucionado desde que decidí dejar de seguir esos eventos. En fin, gracias por la actualización y la aclaración. Qué penita me ha entrado releyendo algunos de estos posts.

Comment: @user0721090601 she and management reached a settlement of her legal action under terms which neither can disclose. She will not be coming back. I think the mood on MSE has lightened over the last few months and management have taken steps to change some of their behaviour. scanning some recent highly up-voted posts on MSE might help you decide whether those changes are enough to persuade you to stand.

Comment: @mdewey I was actually fairly aware that Monica had left definitively because of SE's refusal to make adequate public ammends.  Between that, actions against other users as noted by both fedorqui and Diego, and JNat's refusal to apologize to me for previous unreasonable actions against me, I wouldn't actually serious consider throwing in my hat.    The only reason I even come onto SE these days is to help support those learning a programming language I do considerable work with since SE is regrettably still the de facto place people look for help